# Training for custom object detection is failing

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

I am trying to run Object Detection model from tensorflow to train for a custom object. I am doing it on my macbook. I have completed all the previous step of installation and every step is verified.

But when I tried to run the training using this command

```
python3 legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

I am getting this and the training quits:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py:125: main (from **main**) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use object_detection/model_main.py.
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py:265: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
>   WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py:1205: calling squeeze (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with squeeze_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use the axis argument instead
>   INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[273]], model variable shape: [[6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[273]], model variable shape: [[6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[273]], model variable shape: [[6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[273]], model variable shape: [[6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 273]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 273]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 273]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 273]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 6]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 1024, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 512, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 512, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 256, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/biases/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[546]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 128, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 128, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 128, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 128, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 128, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 128, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/weights/RMSProp_1] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 128, 546]], model variable shape: [[1, 1, 128, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
>   WARNING:root:Variable [global_step] is not available in checkpoint
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py:737: Supervisor.**init** (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py:737: Supervisor.**init** (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
>   2018-08-27 11:22:35.947856: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>   INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ssd_mobilenet_v1/model.ckpt
>   INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ssd_mobilenet_v1/model.ckpt
>   INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
>   INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
>   INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , channels attribute 4 does not match bits per pixel from file 3
>        [[Node: case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/DecodeBmp = DecodeBmp[channels=0, _device="/device:CPU:0"](case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/DecodeGif/Switch_1, ^case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_2/Assert, ^case/Assert/AssertGuard/Merge, ^case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert)]]
>        [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext_class=["loc:@RandomHorizontalFlip/cond_1/Switch_1"], output_shapes=[[], [?], [?,4], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?,?,3], [], [], []], output_types=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>   INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , channels attribute 4 does not match bits per pixel from file 3
>        [[Node: case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/DecodeBmp = DecodeBmp[channels=0, _device="/device:CPU:0"](case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/DecodeGif/Switch_1, ^case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_2/Assert, ^case/Assert/AssertGuard/Merge, ^case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert)]]
>        [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext_class=["loc:@RandomHorizontalFlip/cond_1/Switch_1"], output_shapes=[[], [?], [?,4], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?,?,3], [], [], []], output_types=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>   2018-08-27 11:22:53.122315: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at queue_op.cc:109 : Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 18. Expected [1,?,?,3], got [1,86,96,4]
>   2018-08-27 11:22:53.144706: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at queue_op.cc:109 : Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 18. Expected [1,?,?,3], got [1,244,123,4]
>   2018-08-27 11:22:54.211976: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at queue_op.cc:109 : Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 18. Expected [1,?,?,3], got [1,248,148,4]
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
>   INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training. FIFOQueue '_3_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
>        [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Caused by op 'prefetch_queue_Dequeue', defined at:
  File "legacy/train.py", line 184, in 
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 272, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "legacy/train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 290, in train
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 180, in _create_losses
    train_config.use_multiclass_scores)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 123, in get_inputs
    read_data_list = input_queue.dequeue()
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/core/batcher.py", line 111, in dequeue
    batched_tensors = self._queue.dequeue()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 433, in dequeue
    self._queue_ref, self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 3734, in queue_dequeue_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in **init**
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_3_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training. FIFOQueue '_3_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Caused by op 'prefetch_queue_Dequeue', defined at:
  File "legacy/train.py", line 184, in 
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 272, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "legacy/train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 290, in train
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 180, in _create_losses
    train_config.use_multiclass_scores)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 123, in get_inputs
    read_data_list = input_queue.dequeue()
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/core/batcher.py", line 111, in dequeue
    batched_tensors = self._queue.dequeue()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 433, in dequeue
    self._queue_ref, self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 3734, in queue_dequeue_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in **init**
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_3_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "legacy/train.py", line 184, in 
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 272, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "legacy/train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/Users/AbhiramGandhe/Documents/tf_files/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 415, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 785, in train
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 833, in stop
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 252, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1205, in _single_operation_run
    self._call_tf_sessionrun(None, {}, [], target_list, None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: channels attribute 4 does not match bits per pixel from file 3
     [[Node: case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/DecodeBmp = DecodeBmp[channels=0, _device="/device:CPU:0"](case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/DecodeGif/Switch_1, ^case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_2/Assert, ^case/Assert/AssertGuard/Merge, ^case/cond/cond_jpeg/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext_class=["loc:@RandomHorizontalFlip/cond_1/Switch_1"], output_shapes=[[], [?], [?,4], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?,?,3], [], [], []], output_types=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]'

** Can you plase help me to identify where should I concentrate to resolve this?**
There are multiple issues it seems but I am unable to find a way to get past it. Can you please help in resolving this?